Why am I getting leftover text in decrypted file?
I am developing a file encryption utility program (in C language) for the Windows operating system using only the Windows API. The program provide a command-line interface (CLI) for users to encrypt and decrypt files using AES-256 encryption algorithm. But when the program decrypts the encrypted text file, there is some text added at the end of the original text of source file.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 260
#define AES_KEY_SIZE 32
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16

bool encryptFile(char* sourcePath, char* destPath, char* password);
bool decryptFile(char* sourcePath, char* destPath, char* password);
void handleError(DWORD errorCode);

int main() {
    char choice;
    printf("1: Encrypt\n");
    printf("2: Decrypt\n\n");
    printf("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a file?  ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    getchar();

    if (choice == '1') {
        char sourcePath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
        char destPath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
        char password[100];

        printf("Enter Source File Path: ");
        fgets(sourcePath, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, stdin);
        sourcePath[strcspn(sourcePath, "\n")] = 0;

        printf("Enter Encryption Password: ");
        fgets(password, 100, stdin);
        password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = 0;

        printf("Enter Destination File Path (or press 's' for same path): ");
        fgets(destPath, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, stdin);
        destPath[strcspn(destPath, "\n")] = 0;

        if (destPath[0] == 's') {
            strcpy(destPath, sourcePath);
            char* ext = strrchr(destPath, '.');
            if (ext != NULL) {
                *ext = '\0';
            }
            strcat(destPath, "_Encrypted.txt"); // Preserve original file extension
        }

        if (encryptFile(sourcePath, destPath, password)) {
            printf("File Encrypted Successfully: %s\n", destPath);
        } else {
            printf("Error Encrypting File.\n");
        }
    } else if (choice == '2') {
        char sourcePath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
        char destPath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
        char password[100];

        printf("Enter Source File Path: ");
        fgets(sourcePath, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, stdin);
        sourcePath[strcspn(sourcePath, "\n")] = 0;

        printf("Enter Decryption Password: ");
        fgets(password, 100, stdin);
        password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = 0;

        printf("Enter Destination File Path (or press 's' for same path): ");
        fgets(destPath, MAX_PATH_LENGTH, stdin);
        destPath[strcspn(destPath, "\n")] = 0;

        if (destPath[0] == 's') {
            strcpy(destPath, sourcePath);
            char* ext = strrchr(destPath, '.');
            if (ext != NULL) {
                *ext = '\0';
            }
            strcat(destPath, "_Decrypted.txt"); // Preserve original file extension
        }

        if (decryptFile(sourcePath, destPath, password)) {
            printf("File Decrypted Successfully: %s\n", destPath);
        } else {
            printf("Error Decrypting File.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

bool encryptFile(char* sourcePath, char* destPath, char* password) {
    // Open the source file for reading
    FILE* hSourceFile = fopen(sourcePath, "rb");
    if (hSourceFile == NULL) {
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    // Open the destination file for writing
    FILE* hDestFile = fopen(destPath, "wb");
    if (hDestFile == NULL) {
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    if (!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)password, strlen(password), 0)) {
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    if (!CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0, &hKey)) {
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    BYTE buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesWritten;
    BOOL success = TRUE;

    while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, hSourceFile)) > 0) {
        DWORD encryptedSize = ((bytesRead + AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        BYTE* encryptedBuffer = (BYTE*)malloc(encryptedSize);
        if (encryptedBuffer == NULL) {
            CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
            CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
            CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
            fclose(hSourceFile);
            fclose(hDestFile);
            return false;
        }

        memcpy(encryptedBuffer, buffer, bytesRead);

        success = CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, FALSE, 0, encryptedBuffer, &encryptedSize, encryptedSize);
        if (!success) {
            free(encryptedBuffer);
            break;
        }

        fwrite(encryptedBuffer, 1, encryptedSize, hDestFile);
        free(encryptedBuffer);
    }

    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
    fclose(hSourceFile);
    fclose(hDestFile);

    if (!success) {
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


bool decryptFile(char* sourcePath, char* destPath, char* password) {
    // Open the source file for reading
    FILE* hSourceFile = fopen(sourcePath, "rb");
    if (hSourceFile == NULL) {
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    // Open the destination file for writing
    FILE* hDestFile = fopen(destPath, "wb");
    if (hDestFile == NULL) {
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    if (!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)password, strlen(password), 0)) {
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    if (!CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0, &hKey)) {
        CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        fclose(hSourceFile);
        fclose(hDestFile);
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    BYTE bufferIn[BUFFER_SIZE];
    BYTE bufferOut[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesWritten;
    BOOL success = TRUE;

    while ((bytesRead = fread(bufferIn, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, hSourceFile)) > 0) {
        memcpy(bufferOut, bufferIn, bytesRead);
        success = CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, FALSE, 0, bufferOut, &bytesRead);
        if (!success) {
            break;
        }
        fwrite(bufferOut, 1, bytesRead, hDestFile);
    }

    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
    fclose(hSourceFile);
    fclose(hDestFile);

    if (!success) {
        handleError(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void handleError(DWORD errorCode) {
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        errorCode,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL
    );
    printf("Error: %s\n", (LPCSTR)lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

What can be the problem in the code?

Do not tag C++ if the program is written in C.

You are not using the windows interface, as you have declared a main() routine, you should use winMain() or similar.  Windows OS departs severely from the normal C APIs.

I'd need to see the output to confirm this, but there's a good chance that this extra text is padding that's been added to the plaintext to make sure it's a multiple of the blocksize. For AES, the blocksize is 128bit

It was an issue of padding. I used PKCS#7 padding, which adds bytes with values equal to the number of padding bytes needed. PKCS#7 padding specifies how many bytes are added as padding, so It can be easily determined and removed after decryption.
